# php mail-form with multiple file attachment plugin

Tags: php, jquery, attachment

```
<p><input type="file" name="file[]" class="multi" accept="gif|jpg"/></p>
```

With the above, I can get all the results in $_FILES. However the pictures are not getting through the foreach loop it seems.

```
<p><input type="file" name="file1" class="multi" accept="gif|jpg"/></p>
<p><input type="file" name="file2" class="multi" accept="gif|jpg"/></p>
```

When doing it like above, then the code does work - and the loop seems to run just fine. I have searched all over the place about the multiple file plugin and how to get it to work. Although I am positive that I am overlooking a error in the foreach loop with my method.

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>E-mail with Attachment</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"        
language="javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.MultiFile.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript">   
</script>

</head>
<body>
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){

$to="you@mail.com";
$subject="E-mail with attachment";

$from = stripslashes($_POST['fromname'])."<".stripslashes($_POST['fromemail']).">";

$mime_boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_x".md5(mt_rand())."x";

$headers = "From: $from\r\n" .
"MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
  "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
  " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

$message="This is an example";

$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
  "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
  "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
$message . "\n\n";


foreach($_FILES as $userfile){

  $tmp_name = $userfile['tmp_name'];
  $type = $userfile['type'];
  $name = $userfile['name'];
  $size = $userfile['size'];


  if (file_exists($tmp_name)){

     if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_name)){

        $file = fopen($tmp_name,'rb');

        // read the file content into a variable
        $data = fread($file,filesize($tmp_name));

        fclose($file);

        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
     }

     $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
        "Content-Type: {$type};\n" .
        " name=\"{$name}\"\n" .
        "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
        " filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
     $data . "\n\n";
   }
   }


 // here's our closing mime boundary that indicates the last of the message
 $message.="--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
 // now we just send the message
 if (@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
  print_r($_FILES);
 else
  echo "Failed to send";
 } else {
?>
<p>Send an e-mail with an attachment:</p>
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" 
  enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1">
  <p>Your name: <input type="text" name="fromname"></p>
  <p>Your e-mail: <input type="text" name="fromemail"></p>
  <p>Mod List: <textarea  name="question" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"   
   name="modlist"></textarea>
  <p><input type="file" name="file[]" class="multi" accept="gif|jpg"/></p>
  <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></p>
  </form>
  <?php } ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

The plugin:

http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/#tab-Uploading

Hopefully its a small error that I am overlooking in the foreach loop, thanks in advance.